# App like Paintweb?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm looking to do some annotation and mark-up of images on my website, then save them back to the server.  So, it would be like this...
1.) User uploads image.
2.) I annotate on it in the browser.
3.) The annotated image is saved (either as a new image or overwriting the uploaded one).

I've been looking at http://code.google.com/p/paintweb/ and it looks all good.  Except the text tool is not very good.  Are there any alternatives anyone knows about?  Maybe an HTML5 solution?  Canvas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try search in alternativeto.net and filter by license or platform.
This is the link : [Paintweb](http://alternativeto.net/SearchResult.aspx?search=Paintweb)